# Store JSONB PostgreSQL data type column into Athena

Tags: postgresql, csv, jsonb, amazon-athena

I am creating an Athena external table on a CSV that I generated from my PostgreSQL database.

The csv contains a columns that has a *jsonb* datatype.
If possible, I want to exclude this column from the table created in Athena, or kindly suggest a way to include this datatype.